# What is the mathamatical term for this programming concept?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, computer-science, factorial

In python's itertools, there is a function called permutations. It returns the number of ways to arrange x number of variables into a given space.

For example,

```
permutations("ABC", 2) == [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]
```

The first argument is the number of variables, and the second is the size of each group.

This concept is similar to factorial, but you don't use every variable in each group.

Side question: Is there a mathematical term for all of the differnt permuation size added up all the way to factorial, e.g, permutations("ABC", 1)+permutations("ABC", 2)+permutations("ABC", 3)

Sorry if this is a silly question. I am just a HS student.

Comment: So you want a name for {(), (A), (B), (C), (A,B), (A,C), (B,A), (B,C), (C,A), (C,B), (A,B,C), (A,C,B), (B,A,C), (B,C,A), (C,A,B), (C,B,A)}?  Idunno, but you got me curious.

Comment: You want $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{^nP_i} $

Comment: I was wondering if there is a name for ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), But if there is a name for that sequence, I would be interested in that to.

Comment: That's the 2-permutations of ('A', 'B', 'C').  Dunno if the glomming of all of them has a name or even a common use --- actually, now that I think about it I had a task earlier this week that involved the 0- 1- 2- and 3- permutations of a 6-entry list.

Comment: $k$-permutations. That's it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n

Comment: Are you looking for the *number of ways* to do it, or an actual *listing* of all of the ways?  In your question body you say you want to know the number, but in your example you produce a list.

Comment: I am only looking for a number. I was just demonstrating the concept.

Comment: I would call these "partial permutations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(n)$ is the sum of **k-permutations of n**, then
\[
f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!},\ \mbox{for}\ n\ge1
\]